# For the first TextBox txtName, it is showing a dropdown list but for the other TextBox i am not getting any dropdownlist

Tags: c#

Below code is of .net windows form app showing 2 TextBoxes with drop down suggestion when user types something in it. the code for first TextBox txtName is working but the other one is not....i need hellp on this.

```
private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-H1PE2LT;Initial Catalog=HealthandWellness;Integrated Security=True";
        connection.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Medicine Name] FROM Details", connection); 
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            collection.Add(reader["Medicine Name"].ToString());
        }
    }


private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-H1PE2LT;Initial Catalog=HealthandWellness;Integrated Security=True";
        connection.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Medicine Name] FROM Details", connection);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection collection1 = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            collection1.Add(reader["Medicine Name"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your front end code where you identify the call to the textBox1_Texthanged call.  You may just have typo in the calling of that object/function.

Comment: Why are you instantiating a new `AutoCompleteStringCollection` for each row retrieved from the query? You're only going to get the last row of the result set in the drop-down list.

Comment: And it doesnt look like you are closing your SQL connection

Comment: Show us the code where you wire up the event handlers to the text boxes.

Comment: And where are you telling the textbox to set the autocompletcustomsource? And why are you doing this kind of task in a textchanged event. This will happen every time you type or remove a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say that one of these is working and the other is not leads me to believe that you have set up something in the gui properties because I see nowhere where you set this stringcollection to your autocompletecustomsource. That being said, let's use 2 new textboxes and set up a demo that you can test on your own machine.

For the building of the AutoCompleteStringCollection, I'm going to just use a list but you would use your query. I will try to denote where you would use those methods.

Since you're using the same data for both textboxes, we only need to create the collection once. We'll do this in the form load.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this would be replaced with your query results from the database
        string[] input = { "able", "alpha", "baker", "bravo", "charlie", "charcoal", "dog", "delta", "eagle", "foxtrot" };
        List<string> pretendThisCameFromAQuery = new List<string>(input);

        //define an AutoCompleteStringCollection. Notice it is outside of the loop as you want to add to this with each iteration of the read() or in this case the foreach loop i'm using.
        AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        //here is where your While reader.read() would go
        foreach (string item in pretendThisCameFromAQuery)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
            //your code here would be something like
            //collection.Add(reader["Medicine Name"].ToString());
        }

        //so now we have a collection. Who wants to use it.

        //for txtName1, we'll set it up to just suggest.

        txtName1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
        txtName1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        txtName1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

        //for textbox2 we'll use suggestappend.
        //notice no new collection needed.
        textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
        textBox2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
```

Notice that this code is not in any of the textbox events. Especially the TextChanged event as that would run with every change to the textbox and we don't need to do that as we only need to fill the collection and assign it to the textbox(s) that we want to use the collection with before we need to use the dropdown.

Again, if you run this demo, I strongly suggest you add two new textboxes named as I have them named because I really feel you've done something outside of writing code to get the first one to work.

Comment: @HarshalSawant if this answered your question please mark it as the answer so that others may find it when having similar issues.